# How to play .oga or .ogg file in ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audio-player, ogg

I want to play .ogg/.oga audio files from a remote URL in my iOS app. I also want to play audio even when the app is in background state.

I have tried https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer this player, but it cannot play from remote URLs and only play local audio in foreground state.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any player that does that directly, but there are a couple of OGG decoding libraries that you can use in iOS:

- The Xiph libraries which you can find [precompiled for iOS](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/08/07/precompiled-ogg-vorbis-libraries-for-ios/).
- A [public domain OGG Vorbis decoder library](http://www.nothings.org/stb_vorbis/) which is contained in a standalone C file and therefore is easy to integrate into any project.

You would have to pass the streaming data to the decoder and play the decoded samples. For this you could save the decoded samples into a buffer and play them with an [AVAudioPlayerNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayernode).

> I also want to play audio even app is in background state.

There is an app capability in iOS that enables you to [play background audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio).